Gender of "idem/ders. or dies." when same author in
When I am citing someone and he/she is author of the cited article but also publisher of the same collection, where the article is published in, I always get the German "ders." (male gender) in the citation although when the author is female or when it's the same couple of author, what would require "dies." (female / plural).
Can someone help me?
I'm using the following setting. It might be a bit messy, as I am no pro and only puzzling what I need. I am sorry if it is to chaotic ^^
\documentclass[]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[style=footnote-dw, natbib=true, nopublisher=false, urldate=long, citepages=separate, idembib=false, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiveni}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  and      = {u\adddot},
  editor   = {Hg\adddot},
  editors  = {Hg\adddot},
  byeditor = {hg\adddot\thinspace v\adddotspace},
  thiscite = {hier\addcolon\thinspace},
  number   = {Heft},
}

\renewcommand*\postnotedelim{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibrevsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}


\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}

\renewcommand*{\jourvolstring}{\addperiod\space}
\renewcommand*{\jourvolnumsep}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}


\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\adddot\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{useeditor+others}%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \setunit{\jourvolstring}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \ifbool{bbx:journumdate}
    {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle+date}}
    {\ifbool{bbx:journumafteryear}
      {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle+afteryear}}
      {\usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle+standard}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle+standard}{%
  \setunit*{\jourvolnumsep}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{issue+date}}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \iflistundef{location}
    {\setunit*{\adddot\space}}
    {\setunit*{\adddot\space}}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}





Hi there! Firstly I can’t reproduce your code. I don’t think I have got the MastersDoctoralThesis class and I get some problems if I don’t remove the remreset package. About MWE, see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/236280; https://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html
Actually, you have to give also a MWEB, i.e. you have to share also a .bib file.
Indeed, my doubt is: have you already filled the gender list within each entry of your .bib file? E.g.: Have you got something like @article{baez/article,    author={Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},gender={pm}} ... etc.?

Hi Francesco, Thank you for your comment! I have to admit my understanding of using LaTeX is totally based on learning by doing. I took the MastersDoctoralThesis template and adjusted it to what I need. I am absolutely no pro and only have minimal understanding of how it all works, but it actually works for my 400+ pages text. ^^
So please excuse that my requested did not include the information you need. The .bib file is generated via Citvati and I upload it to Overleaf. When I open the file in overleaf it only shows each title entry (books, articles etc) like followin: (next comment)

'''@book{Abbate.2012,
author = {Abbate, Carolyn and Parker, Roger},
year = {2012},
title = {A History of Opera},
publisher = {{Penguin Books}},
subtitle = {The Last Four Hundred Years},
location = {London},
abstract = {}
}'''

Ok. I reassure you: the «learning by doing» is a great way to «learn» and good questions in fora like StackExchange are necessary to improve your skills, day after day. Well: can you modify this .bib file? If yes, fill the gender list: @book{Abbate.2012,    author = {Abbate, Carolyn and Parker, Roger},    gender={pp},     year = {2012},    title = {A History of Opera},    subtitle = {The Last Four Hundred Years},    publisher = {Penguin Books},    location = {London}}. You can fill the gender list with sm, sf, sn, pm, pf, pn and pp. See biblatex documentation, p. 28.

Overleaf has got nice templates and tutorials too. So, don’t worry, if you are a beginner. It’s normal to work even by chance.

Thank you for your understanding!
The .bib file is generated via Citavi. So maybe I need to fix it there? I can modify the .bib file on Overleaf, but each time I upload the newest databank from Citavi (when I add a new book), then I would need to rewrite the handmade modifications, right?

It’s the first time I meet with this software. I looked around online a bit, but it isn’t accessible, so I can’t see if there’s anything that can be done. Well, I think I understand the problem: if you can’t get the software to include the gender list, you could try working with an independent .bib file, without going through Citavi. I mean: copy the Citavi database to your own (e.g. main.bib) and reference just the latter; finally, input just \addbibresource{main.bib}. If you really can’t get the software to include the gender list, it might be a suitable solution.

https://www1.citavi.com/sub/manual5/en/adding_the_gender_information.html I guess, but we're no longer in the scope of a tex question...

Thank you. It could be it is a matter somewhere between Citavi and LaTeX. On Citavi the gender is correctly set up. Maybe it has to do with the export or the way the LaTeX document is reading the export. I don't know.
